# Scala Play Framework Discarding Cookies questions

Tags: java, scala, cookies, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hi I have some trouble using the Discarding Cookies function in the Play Framework for Scala

I have used set cookies with the domain x.y.z.com I am trying to discard the cookie but the DiscardingCookie I made has the same name, but the domain is set to y.z.com. Will the cookie be discarded? Or does the domain need to match 100% and would not work on subdomains in order for the cookie to be discarded.

Also if I set a cookie on abc.com but get directed to another page where the cookie does not exist, but then from the new redirect, make a DiscardingCookie call to discard the cookie that is not there anymore, will that cookie be discarded once I return to abc.com? or Is that cookie out of scope since I am no longer on the correct domain

Answer (score 0):

The `DiscardingCookie` case class definition goes as follows:

```
/**
 * A cookie to be discarded.  This contains only the data necessary for discarding a cookie.
 *
 * @param name the name of the cookie to discard
 * @param path the path of the cookie, defaults to the root path
 * @param domain the cookie domain
 * @param secure whether this cookie is secured
 */
case class DiscardingCookie(name: String, path: String = "/", domain: Option[String] = None, secure: Boolean = false) {
  def toCookie = Cookie(name, "", Some(-86400), path, domain, secure)
}
```

As you can see there is a `domain` parameter. Just set it to `Some("x.y.z.com")` and it should work for you.